# Mounting temporary swap partition on boot

Tags: boot, partition, swap

I bought some SanDisk 16GB U100 SSD's off of eBay and discovered that they had a peculiar problem; they act like RAM in that they can be partitioned/formatted/etc., all test come back positive, and if you install an OS, you can reboot into it just fine.   ...until you turn the computer off.  When you power it back up, the drives are wiped utterly clean like you didn't do anything.  I was unable to find out what was going on, but what occurred to me was that, as they work perfectly fine while powered, I might be able to use them as swap drives in my computers.  Is it possible to add a command somewhere to set them up during the boot cycle to give me a fast swap partition?  What might some issues be?  I use mostly Debian-based distros--Lubuntu & Slax, mostly.  (I consider myself a Linux newbie, so detailed instructions would be **very** much appreciated.  I also realize that I don't even know what further information you might need to be able to help me.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be worried they're counterfeit and fraudulent; that's not an expected failure mode of an SSD (expected failure mode is it goes read-only, and of course completely fails is possible too). I'd be wary of trusting them to store data even when powered on. Unless you've done extensive testing, I'd guess the actual behavior is that they have some amount of RAM that is returning the most-recent X bytes of data. So, that's the cache and the flash has failed but the controller doesn't realize it; or, it's the fraud someone committed (omitting the flash entirely).

So, it's relatively easy to tell Linux to use them a swap — just run `mkswap /dev/WHATEVER` and `swapon /dev/WHATER` (`/dev/disk/by-id/…` would be easiest, if they have stable IDs), you could put that in a systemd service or other boot script... but I really wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, but might be a fix for your SanDisk's. There's a firmware update from Lenovo available, one for Windows and one as bootable ISO. I don't know if that fixes your problem or if this update works on non-Lenovo branded U100 SSDs, but it might be worth a try.

1. [Sandisk SSD Firmware Update for Windows 7 (32-bit, 64-bit), Windows 8 (32-bit, 64-bit) - IdeaPad U310, U410, U510](https://support.lenovo.com/de/en/downloads/ds100326)

   ```
   U100_10.52_10.54_to_10.56_v1.0.0.0_Loader-v1.7_041014.zip
   Sandisk SSD Firmware Upgrade
   ```
2. [Solid State Drive firmware update utility (Bootable ISO) - ThinkPad](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/migr-69806)

   From the [README for Solid State Drive Firmware Update Utility](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/fwss31en.txt):

   ```
   <FWSS29>
   [Firmware]
      Model               Firmware
      ----------------    --------------
      [ SanDisk ]
      SSD U100            10.56.01

   -(New) Support SanDisk SSD U100.
   ```